# Java equals method not behaving as expected

Tags: java

```
package restaurantclient;

public class Restaurant extends Store {

//Instance Variables
private int peopleServed; 
private double averagePrice; 

//Constructor with 3 parameters
public Restaurant(String storename, int peopleServed, double averagePrice) {
super(storename);
setPeopleServed(peopleServed);
setAveragePrice(averagePrice);
}

//Getters (Accessors)
public int getPeopleServed() { 
return peopleServed; 
} 

public double getAveragePrice() { 
return averagePrice; 
} 

//Setters (Mutators)
public void setPeopleServed(int peopleServed) { 
this.peopleServed = peopleServed; 
}

public void setAveragePrice(double averagePrice) { 
this.averagePrice = averagePrice; 
} 

//toString Method [Must Override]
@Override
public String toString() {
    String information = "Store name: " + (super.getName());
    information += "\n" + "The number of people served: " + peopleServed;
    information += "\n" + "The average price per person: $" + averagePrice;

    return information;
    }

//Equals Method
@Override
public boolean equals (Object other) {

    if (this == other)
        return true;
    if (other == null)
        return false;
    if (!(other instanceof Restaurant))
        return false;

   Restaurant otherRestaurant = (Restaurant) other;

    if (this.getName() == null) {
        if (otherRestaurant.getName() != null)
            return false;
    }   else if (!(this.getName().equals(otherRestaurant.getName())))
            return false;

    if (peopleServed == -1) {
        if (otherRestaurant.peopleServed != -1)
            return false;
    }   else if (peopleServed != (otherRestaurant.peopleServed))
            return false;

    if (averagePrice == -1) {
        if (otherRestaurant.averagePrice != -1)
            return false;
    }   
        else if (averagePrice != (otherRestaurant.averagePrice))
            return false;

    return true;
}


public double getAverageTaxes() { 
double total; 
total = this.getPeopleServed() * this.getAveragePrice() 
* super.CA_TAX_RATE; 
return total; 
} 
}


   package restaurantclient;


public class Store {

//Instance Variables
protected final double CA_TAX_RATE = 0.0884; 
private String storename; 

//Constructor
public Store(String storename) { 
    setName(storename); 
    } 

//Getters (Accessors)
public String getName() { 
    return storename; 
    } 

//Setters (Mutators)
public void setName(String storename) { 
    this.storename = storename; 
    } 

//toString Method [Must Override]
@Override
public String toString() {
    String directory = "Name of store: " + storename;

    return directory;
    }

//Equals Method
public boolean equals (Store storename) {

    if (this == storename)
        return true;
    if (storename == null)
        return false;
    if (!(storename instanceof Store))
        return false;

    return true;

    }

}
```

Above are the equals methods I'm calling. They are displaying the wrong answers: it should be in the first instance, "They are not equal" and in the second instance after setting everything equal to each other, it should display, "They are equal". I have tried very hard on this problem and many things have not worked. There are no overt errors it runs fine, but I am doing something wrong and some precise guidance would be a lot of help. Much of the vague hints have got me nowhere. I need something concrete, if this makes to you. Thanks again for the help. The following is the Client class:

```
package restaurantclient;  

public class RestaurantClient { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Restaurant r1 = new Restaurant("McDonald's", 1000000, 8.00);
    Restaurant r2 = new Restaurant("KFC", 500000, 6.00);

    System.out.println(r1.toString());
    System.out.println(r2.toString());
    System.out.println();

    r2.setAveragePrice(r1.getAveragePrice());
    r2.setPeopleServed(r1.getPeopleServed());

    System.out.println(r1.toString());
    System.out.println(r2.toString());

    if (r1.equals(r2))  {
        System.out.println("The objects are equal.");
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("The objects are not equal."); //SHOULD say "not equal" here EVERY TIME the second instance (next comment down) says "Equal"...this should never change. 
        System.out.println();
        }

    System.out.println();
    r2.setName(r1.getName());

    System.out.println(r1.toString());
    System.out.println(r2.toString());

    if (r1.equals(r2)) {
        System.out.println("The objects are equal."); //Now that everything is equal, it should print "The Objects are Equal" but it doesn't. It's in lock-step with the previous instance. Changing some things like return true to return false might make both these instances "Are equal" and some might change them to "Not Equal" but they are never the way I want them, which is when 2 changes are made, they are not equal (first case) and when the third and final change is made (like this case here on this line) it should say "the obj are equal" but it doesn't. 
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The objects are not equal.");
        System.out.println();
    }    

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("The avg. annual taxes paid by the restaurant is: $");
    System.out.println(r1.getAverageTaxes());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of that input? looks ok at the 1st sight!

Comment: equals method is using the name, people served and avg price... with that criteria mcDonalds and kfc must return false in th equals method...

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `super.getName()` ?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter here, but you should also override [`hashcode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) whenever you override `equals`.

Comment: @AxelH she did that after the 1st equals check... and changing just the name must give the same result back

Comment: I need it to return "not equal" the first time (because only 2 out of the 3 arguments are equal the first instance) and then "equal" the second time (because 3/3 arguments will return equal and they do when you see them displayed, but the "equal" is not shown)

Comment: Also just as a FYI, I did do the override hashcode , but it didn't change anything when I ran it so I left it out.

Comment: souldnt you use `return true;` at the end of the 2 equals functions? (you test all cases of differences between objects, if there are none they should be equal).. Also i think it should be `this.getName` instead of `super`

Comment: Was told to use super as a parameter in the constructor

Comment: Setting both `public boolean equals` to `true` results in both being "equal" instead of 1st instance "not equal" and 2nd instance "equal"...so the problem is flipped now.

Comment: @SarahSanchez, running the code you have posted in the edit gaves me first `not equal` then `equal`... are you sure you are running the correct code (clean the project)

Comment: how do i clean the project? do you mean restart it? i should note that i had another project open but i closed it and it still gave me the wrong output. i will try to restart it now.

Comment: @SarahSanchez, what IDE are you using ? PS : this seems more like what I expecting to be honnest ;)

Comment: still not getting the right display even after restarting netbeans. how in the world are you getting the right output? what ide are you using?

Comment: @SarahSanchez With Netbeans, `right click` on the project name, then `clean`. This will remove every previous compilation file. This should do it. Restarting doesn't remove the compiled class, so this doesn't help ;) This is why the answers proposed didn't worked, the updates wasn't noticed.

Comment: I tried `clean` and `clean and build` but it didn't work...oh  no.... :(

Comment: @SarahSanchez, I am sorry, I am stupid !! I didn't copy the equals method of `Store`. So the problem is simple, since you are overriding `equals(Object)` but are calling it directly with a `Restaurant` (a `Store`), this use the `Store.equals` since it is matching the type. `equals` should accept `Object` in Store..

Comment: BINGO! THANK YOU! SOLVED THE PROBLEM! <3

Comment: @SarahSanchez I took way to much time to notice it (since you have write those two from the beginning)... sorry ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that I see is simple, you are not getting the same `name`.

In equals, you are comparing `super.getName()` with `otherRestaurant.getName()`

If the superclass of Restaurant have a different format or return an other variable, since you compare it to `Restaurant.getName()`, this will compare different value. Using `this.getName()` to compare the same variable (or format of variable) is safer. **Even if `Restaurant.getName()` is only returning the `super.getName()`, this would be safer if you changed the method of Restaurant (because you prefer it an other way).**

Here is an example :

Restaurant:

```
public String getName(){
    return "A restaurant " + name;
}
```

Super class :

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

Will result into comparing `"A restaurant : KFC"` with `"KFV"`.

Using the same getter assure you to return the same "format".

---

Aslo, your logic is wrong. You want to check if one of the value is different, if it is, `return false`. And if you reach the end of the method, meaning there where no difference leading to a `return false`, you `return true`.

```
if (this.getName() == null) {
    if (otherRestaurant.getName() != null)
        return false;
}   else if (!super.getName().equals(otherRestaurant.getName())) // added ! here
        return false;

if (peopleServed == -1) {
    if (otherRestaurant.peopleServed != -1)
        return false;
}   else if (peopleServed != (otherRestaurant.peopleServed)) // change to != here
        return false;

if (averagePrice == -1) {
    if (otherRestaurant.averagePrice != -1)
        return false;
}   
    else if (averagePrice != (otherRestaurant.averagePrice)) // change to != here
        return false;

//No differences, then it is equals.
return true;
```

Note :

This condition could be shorten

```
if (averagePrice == -1) {
    if (otherRestaurant.averagePrice != -1)
        return false;
}   
    else if (averagePrice != (otherRestaurant.averagePrice)) // change to != here
        return false;
```

Since it is doing the same thing (comparing the values) :

```
if (averagePrice != (otherRestaurant.averagePrice))
    return false;
```

---

Edit :

You are having a problem of overriding.

In Store:

```
public boolean equals(Store s){}
```

And in Restaurant

```
public boolean equals(Object o){}
```

Since you are calling the method with a `Restaurant` (subclass of `Store`), the JVM will use the `Store.equals` method since it match the type, `Restaurant.equals` is not overriding it, it override the method in `Object`. Change to `Store.equals(Object o)` to correct this.

The method `equals` comes from `Object` so it should be always receiving an `Object` to prevent any problem like this one, if you specify the type in a method, it will not override correctly the method (depending on the type)

Comment: I changed the `otherRestaurant.getName()` to `this.getName()` but the problem still persists. I changed it in 2 places inside the equals method in the "Restaurant" class.

Comment: Thank you for staying with me, @AxelH, I must admit that I did follow Soumik's advice and cleaned up the interrobang placement and whatnot. However, that along with your recommendations have not resolved the issue. I will update my code to reflect what I've done immediately. Thanks again.

Comment: I need to have it (super) in my class......is there a way to fix this problem with super? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I must use `super.getName()` to return the superclass Store name
for comparison or code the `super.equals(Object o)`
method passing the restaurant object reference as an
argument to the superclass equals method to compare
the name. Returns a Boolean. That's what I know, but I don't know how to do it without returning bad values.

Comment: Ok, so I ran `this.getName()` through the equals method and replaced all the `super.getName()` instances, but it still returns bad values. Thanks again for helping :)

Comment: Thank you Axel for the dedication!

Comment: @SarahSanchez You are welcome, for more information, read about overriding and overloading, those are tricky sometimes. (Here this is an overloading since the type are different, not an overiding)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are checking for equality and then returning false, when you should check for not equality to return false.

```
else if (!super.getName().equals(otherRestaurant.getName()))
            return false;

else if (peopleServed != (otherRestaurant.peopleServed))
            return false;

else if (averagePrice != (otherRestaurant.averagePrice))
            return false;
```

Also as asked, any reason to uses super.getName() ?

And since peopleServed & averagePrice cannot be null, the -1 check is not needed as the expected result we be the same as the equality check

And finally, I'm guessing the end return should be true, as it means it's different instance of an object, but they have all the same attributs.

Comment: super is a constraint that I have inside the constructor as a parameter that I need to use. I set all the else if's properly as you mentioned, but I still get the incorrect display even when they return true at the end.

Comment: Well can you details in your test case where you'd expect it to be true ?

Comment: Detail made. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `equals()` method , If `super.name()` equals `otherRestaurant.name()` shouldn't you return `true`, here:

> else if (super.getName().equals(otherRestaurant.getName())) return false;

Comment: I changed it to ! in order to account for that, but it still comes out wrong.

Comment: Can you please post the output i.e the exact answers you are getting. Also who is the super class of Restaurant, and does it implement an equals as well? Would be of help if you posted that as well.

Comment: If `Store` is the superclass, then it's implementation of the `equals` method is wrong. This is assuming that the intention behind having `if (this == other) return true;` within `Restaurant.equals()` is to invoke the super to check for equality. At the moment the `super` always returns false, so it never gets to the point where it starts checking names etc.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, that one will work in any cases:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals (Object other) {

        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof Restaurant))
            return false;

        Restaurant otherRestaurant = (Restaurant) other;

        if (name == null) {
            if (otherRestaurant.getName() != null)
                return false;
        }   else if (name!=otherRestaurant.getName())
            return false;

        if (peopleServed == -1) {
            if (otherRestaurant.peopleServed != -1)
                return false;
        }   else if (peopleServed != otherRestaurant.peopleServed)
            return false;

        if (averagePrice == -1) {
            if (otherRestaurant.averagePrice != -1)
                return false;
        }
        else if (averagePrice != otherRestaurant.averagePrice)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

check it and reply if it is ok

Comment: I need to use super as a parameter inside the constructor. Thank you for the help, though Zheka.

Comment: so change it: 

 _}    else if (super.equals(otherRestaurant.getName()))_

Comment: I changed it, but there was still an error: "storename" is private.

Comment: Without that _storename_ it works fine. In the code that you posted that _store_ class doesnt used. So maybe you should post all the other code?

Comment: i posted the rest of the code. name doesn't work. getName() doesn't work. storename doesn't work. not sure what else to use to get the right equals.

Comment: I guess i finally get what do you want. You want that _name_ of restaurant (inside _equals_ method of restaurant) to reach the superclass _Store_ and took the name store out of it, yea?

Comment: first of all - your method _equals_ at _Restaurant_ doesnt even reach method _equals_ of _Restaurant_. It works with superclass method _equals_ thats why your output is wrong